# Get most recent records from mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Data in my mongoDB collection looks like this

```
{ "_id" : "9115a01f-7ef8-4fb1-aabe-d9a2a7462095", "deviceSerial" : "S121F1194200003", "cbsdId" : "2ABOF-G1-BN3ASI001S121F1194200003", "timestamp" : NumberLong("1652864785973")}
{ "_id" : "70533ece-509d-4a47-829f-0f31e62e1fb2", "deviceSerial" : "S121F1194200003", "cbsdId" : "2ABOF-G1-BN3ASI001S121F1194200003", "timestamp" : NumberLong("1652864785973")}
{ "_id" : "62ad51f3-ad60-4f35-8018-81a8a29d0aa8", "deviceSerial" : "S121F1194200003", "cbsdId" : "2ABOF-G1-BN3ASI001S121F1194200003", "timestamp" : NumberLong("1652864785973")}
{ "_id" : "9d51dda1-d8b4-46f5-81e3-37eb876f785f", "deviceSerial" : "S121F1194200003", "cbsdId" : "2ABOF-G1-BN3ASI001S121F1194200003", "timestamp" : NumberLong("1652864785973")}
{ "_id" : "998e6a86-f8ba-4a5f-80f1-202518713c5e", "deviceSerial" : "S121F1194200003", "cbsdId" : "2ABOF-G1-BN3ASI001S121F1194200003", "timestamp" : NumberLong("1652864811934")}
{ "_id" : "46a39fe7-1ac1-4a96-aec0-0b0b68518405", "deviceSerial" : "S121F1194200003", "cbsdId" : "2ABOF-G1-BN3ASI001S121F1194200003", "timestamp" : NumberLong("1652864811934")}
{ "_id" : "d7072b68-6e98-4d14-b4ff-2ee7b0942f1d", "deviceSerial" : "S121F1194200003", "cbsdId" : "2ABOF-G1-BN3ASI001S121F1194200003", "timestamp" : NumberLong("1652864811934")}
{ "_id" : "afd53c34-1c43-463e-a774-12145bb2a3a9", "deviceSerial" : "S121F1194200003", "cbsdId" : "2ABOF-G1-BN3ASI001S121F1194200003", "timestamp" : NumberLong("1652864811934")}
```

I want to get all rows having most recent timestamp i.e. `all rows having timestamp = select max(timestamp) in collection`. The output should look like:

```
{ "_id" : "9115a01f-7ef8-4fb1-aabe-d9a2a7462095", "deviceSerial" : "S121F1194200003", "cbsdId" : "2ABOF-G1-BN3ASI001S121F1194200003", "timestamp" : NumberLong("1652864785973")}
{ "_id" : "70533ece-509d-4a47-829f-0f31e62e1fb2", "deviceSerial" : "S121F1194200003", "cbsdId" : "2ABOF-G1-BN3ASI001S121F1194200003", "timestamp" : NumberLong("1652864785973")}
{ "_id" : "62ad51f3-ad60-4f35-8018-81a8a29d0aa8", "deviceSerial" : "S121F1194200003", "cbsdId" : "2ABOF-G1-BN3ASI001S121F1194200003", "timestamp" : NumberLong("1652864785973")}
{ "_id" : "9d51dda1-d8b4-46f5-81e3-37eb876f785f", "deviceSerial" : "S121F1194200003", "cbsdId" : "2ABOF-G1-BN3ASI001S121F1194200003", "timestamp" : NumberLong("1652864785973")}
```

I'm new to mongo syntax and I gave it a try but couldn't come up with approach to get above result using single query.
So, far I'm able to get results in sorted order using this:
`db.getCollection('demo').aggregate([{$match:{"deviceSerial":"S121F1194200003"}}, {$sort: {timestamp:-1}}])`

Comment: There is a `$max` aggregate operator, and can be used to get the max value. This can be used with the `$group` aggregate stage.

Comment: @prasad_ I went through that and I was able to get the max timestamp using $max but not all the rows having max(timestamp).

Comment: See these examples about $group - Pivot Data in the MongoDB documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pivot-data

Comment: @prasad_ $group returns one doc per group but I need whole group having max(timestamp)

Comment: Look at the examples in the link in my previous comment. You also need to use `$push: "$$ROOT"` into an array. That will give you all the related documents in the array field. After the group stage, do an `$unwind` on the array field to get all the documents back.